# Parsing a XMl with namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

I m having such type of XML with me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfCustomer 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

<Customer>
<Customer_id>143</Customer_id>
<Cust_last_name>Deutsch</Cust_last_name>
<Cust_first_name>Leslie</Cust_first_name>
<Gender_id>2</Gender_id>
<Email>ldeutsch16@univ.demo</Email>
<Income_id>3</Income_id>
</Customer>

<Customer>
<Customer_id>327</Customer_id>
<Cust_last_name>Marko</Cust_last_name>
<Cust_first_name>Shelby</Cust_first_name>
<Gender_id>1</Gender_id>
<Email>smarko75@free.demo</Email>
<Income_id>5</Income_id>
</Customer>

</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

Can u suggest how to parse it ?

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Comment: You didn't state your problem and it is way too much code. Be more concise. Also, you should format your code, so it is possible to read it without the need of horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're dealing with a collection of Customers. Try making Customer serializable & using XML serialization. YOu may want to check out the link Justin suggested as well.

XML Serialization documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=VS.100).aspx